# Select while instead of While select causing issue

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a ranged date query, and trying to adjust the rules for the loop but I have a bit of a problem:

Take the following:

```
DROP PROCEDURE
IF EXISTS test;
CREATE PROCEDURE test ( IN start_date DATE ) BEGIN
    DECLARE group_name VARCHAR ( 10 ) DEFAULT 'clientA';
    DECLARE service_name VARCHAR ( 10 ) DEFAULT 'serviceA';
    WHILE ( start_date < CURDATE( ) && SUBDATE( start_date, INTERVAL - 2 WEEK ) < CURDATE( ) ) DO
        SELECT start_date AS 'Start Day',   SUBDATE( start_date, INTERVAL - 2 WEEK ) AS 'End Day';
        SET start_date = SUBDATE( start_date, INTERVAL - 2 WEEK );
    END WHILE;
END;
```

This selects a start and end date from a starting point up to today:

> CALL test ( '2019-08-29' );

Returns 5 results:

- 08/29 & 09/12
- 09/12 & 09/26
- 09/26 & 10/10
- 10/10 & 10/24
- 10/24 & 11/7

This is what I want but rather than 5 results. I want each of these as rows in one result. I think the best way to do this is via a sub-query with the inner query running the loop and doing the selects but the outer query serving as a wrapper to constrain them into one set.

I have the following code:

```
    DROP PROCEDURE
    IF EXISTS test;
    CREATE PROCEDURE test ( IN start_date DATE ) BEGIN
        DECLARE group_name VARCHAR ( 10 ) DEFAULT 'clientA';
        DECLARE service_name VARCHAR ( 10 ) DEFAULT 'serviceA';
        SELECT * FROM (WHILE ( start_date < CURDATE( ) && SUBDATE( start_date, INTERVAL - 2 WEEK ) < CURDATE( ) ) DO
            SELECT start_date AS 'Start Day',   SUBDATE( start_date, INTERVAL - 2 WEEK ) AS 'End Day';
            SET start_date = SUBDATE( start_date, INTERVAL - 2 WEEK );
        END WHILE;
)
    END;
```

But that gives me:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS 'Result'  FROM (
>       WHILE ( start_date < CURDATE( ) && SUBDATE( start_date, IN' at line 4

I feel like there's something small wrong with my syntax here but I'm having difficulty understanding exactly what. Any guidance would be great!

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you having to give your newly created procedure permissions to the tables every time you run it?

Comment: No, there are no permissions being granted or changed

Answer (score 1):

you can create a dynamic list of date activity by using MySQL @ variables and joining to any table that has as many rows as you expect in result set... ex: if you need 5, 10 or 1000 records in the dynamic result.

```
select
      -- whatever latest date is BECOMES the Begin Date
      @beginDT BeginDate,
      -- now, add 2 weeks to the @beginDT variable and save as the END Date
      @beginDT := date_add( @beginDT, interval 2 week ) EndDate
   from
      -- pick any table that has as many 2-week cycles as you expect.
      -- ex: if you wanted 1 yr, you would need any table with 26 or 27 records
      AnyTableWithManyRecords,
      -- start the query with your starting date, alias sqlvars is just place-holder
      -- and will only prepare the variable and be one row for rest of query
      ( select @beginDT := '2019-08-29' ) sqlvars
   having
      -- having will stop until your maximum date of interest
      BeginDate < curdate()
   -- but limit to 100 so you don't query against table of millions of records.
   -- how many records do you REALLY need to go through... again, 26 biweekly = 1 year
   -- this limit of 100 would allow for almost 4 yrs worth
   limit 100;
```

Then, if you wanted data from some other table, you could join to the above result set as its own such as

```
select
      SOT.WhateverColumns
   from
      ( above query ) MyDates
         JOIN SomeOtherTable SOT
            on MyDates.BeginDate <= SOT.SomeDate
           AND SOT.SomeDate < MyDates.EndDate
```